SonarQube deletes comments in Pull Request, after initial commit
hope someone will help with my issue!
I use Jenkins + Bitbucket Cloud + SonarQube to analyze code on my project.
Want to use PR decoration function of SonarQube, so it will generate reports on PR (which it does with no issues) and to leave comments directly on the code of PR.
I have an issues with PR comments, so when I create PR it leaves comments in the code. Like this: enter image description here
But if I commit in the brunch after something that touch commented code in any way, I get bage on new commit that code analysis was run and successfull, but all previous comments are dissapearing.
My goal is to make all comments visible on PR unless code that was commented is affected.
Couldn't find a way in Sonar docks that could fix this behaviour, and if it even possible.
